# Index was out of range. It must not be negative and must be smaller than the size of the crowd

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to loop through `PersonalIdentityNumber`but get error:

> Index was out of range. It must not be negative and must be smaller
>   than the size of the crowd.

```
   string connetionString = null;


            SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlReader xmlFile;



            connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=BumsUser;Password=2tusen7Bums";


            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


            using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString)) {
    connection.Open();



            DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;

            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2, CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber", connection);

            for (int i = 0; i < PersonalIdentityNumber.Count; i++) //<--Error
            {

                var personnummer = PersonalIdentityNumber[i];
                var fornamn = FirstName[i];
                var efternamn = LastName[i];
                var lankod = LanKod[i];
                var kommunkod = Kommunkod[i];
                var utdelAdress2 = UtdelAdress2[i];
                var medborgarskapslandKod = MedborgarskapslandKod[i];


                command1.Parameters.Clear();
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", personnummer);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", fornamn);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", efternamn);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", lankod);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", kommunkod);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", utdelAdress2);

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", medborgarskapslandKod);

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", datum);



                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine(personnummer);


   }
          }

                Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

The objects:

```
 List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE> deserializedList = new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>();
            deserializedList = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>();

            var PersonalIdentityNumber = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr).ToList();
            var FirstName = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn).ToList();

            var LastName = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn).ToList();
            var LanKod = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod).ToList();
            var Kommunkod = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod).ToList();

            var UtdelAdress2 = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

I deserialize XML and store the values on those objects.

**My goal** is to update a table in the database with the values from the XML, it works with `foreach` loop but it's difficult to handle that many variables with a `foreach` loop and that is why I wanted it to work with `for` loop

Does anyone know why I get that error?

**UPDATE**

so apparently, the problem was this row:

```
 var utdelAdress2 = UtdelAdress2[i];
```

It was null.

My question is now: Is it possible to make it skip the null values and continue with the rest?

Comment: If you set your exceptions to break when thrown, you will see the exact line of the problem and can inspect the index being used.

Comment: Thank you. I know what the problem is now..I think

Comment: Can you use `IsNullOrEmpty`?